# How can I make an automatic slideshow with both buttons and transition/crossfade?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I would like to make a slideshow much like the example seen on https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots2 (minus the side arrows). I cannot find a way to create an automatic cross-fade transition while retaining the selection buttons at the bottom.

Here is the code given:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <title>W3.CSS</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/w3.css">
 <style>
  .mySlides {display:none}
  .w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
  .w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
 </style>
 <body>
  <div class="w3-container">
   <h2>Slideshow Indicators</h2>
   <p>An example of using buttons to indicate how many slides there are in the slideshow, and which slide the user is currently viewing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-padding-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-padding-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";  
 }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
 }
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
 }
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Update:

```
<style>
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
.mySlides {
    border: none; 
    opacity: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.showMe {opacity: 1;}
</style>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
  <img id="slideimg0" class="mySlides showMe" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="slideimg1" class="mySlides" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="slideimg2" class="mySlides" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}

var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 3;

function nextImage() {
    var e;
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    removeClass(e, "showMe");

    curImage++;
    if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
        curImage = 0;
    }

    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    if (c) c += " "; 
    c += name;
    elem.className = c;
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}
</script>
```

The problem is that I cant get the buttons to funtion

Comment: What have you tried? Instead of just providing all of your code please show the section of what you have tried and an explanation on why you think it didn't work.

Comment: The code I added is the code I found to make the most progress. The cross-fade works, but the buttons completely disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Bootstrap** May be you can solve it easily. try this code with proper *script & stylesheet* adding.......

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works amazingly well! I deleted the anchor tags for the arrows and its almost exactly what I want. Now, do you know if there is a way to change the transition animation? It may be a dumb question, but I only have decent knowledge of HTML, CSS, and some Java.

Comment: With a simple search, I found the answers to my follow up questions. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks @PatrykMoore

Answer (score 0):

```
var slideIndex = 1;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); 
}
//showDivs(slideIndex);
```

and change you html div, that contains the < and > as

```
 <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
```

You can take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) for more info!

Hope it helps!

Comment: The carousel definitely works for making it automatic. But I am still havng two issues. 1) how do I add crossfade? 2) if you go to the link I posted, how would I retain the "selected image buble stays white" effect?

Comment: From what I've researched, it isnt possible to add cross-fade to "display" properties. So, in my updated code, I use "position: absolute" and opacity properties

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/380/?random" alt="Chania">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```